# How to avoid released android app from showing apps package name

Tags: android, google-play, label, release, package-name

I'd like to release my app on the google play store. Currently the app's name is shown right, but in the options to uninstall the app, it's full package name is shown and I'd like to avoid this and instead show the app's name there, too.

Is this possible and if so how would I accomplish it?

Here's my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />

<!-- GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />



<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider12345678"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.app.name.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DiscoverActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_discover"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.app.name.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.app.name.ProfileActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- FACEBOOK ACTIVITY -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FriendsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friends"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <!-- GCM -->


    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <!-- make API to register app to GCM available -->
    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <activity
        android:name=".EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".BasesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bases"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you attach a picture please? I'm looking at a few apps in my phone (one of which is in the playstore, others made for fun and not published, but still installed), and none of them shows the package name. Also I don't remember ever seeing the package name, therefore I had not done anything special to hide it per se.

Comment: hm then i made something wrong. in the application manager it's packagename/applicationid is shown.

Comment: Check your manifest .Check for "android:label" in manifest. What label have you given ?

Comment: it's the name i want it to show

Comment: It's inside the application tag right .? 
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > 
Something like this.

Comment: yes it is inside application tag

Answer (score 1):

android:label was missing in manifests application tag. When I added it first nothing changed but I tested it again today and the "error" is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove  `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` from your application tag in AndroidManifest file ,it will definitely remove the problem.

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)